# Adding Session Request To API Call

Tags: c#, api

I'm unsure how to add the Session Request to the API call as per the Food Hygiene Instructions. I've copied the relevant code and hope I am close, but unsure where to put this one part.

Reference: https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/help

Need to add into the API call: *Session.Request.Headers.Add("x-api-version", 2);*

Partial Code:

```
   readonly string Baseurl = "https://api.ratings.food.gov.uk";
            public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
            {
                List<Authorities> AuthInfo = new List<Authorities>();
    
    
                using var client = new HttpClient
                { 
                //Passing service base url  
                BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl)
                };
    
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                //Define request data format  
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                 
                ***//Session.Request.Headers.Add("x-api-version", 2);***
    
                //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GETRegions using HttpClient  
                HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("Authorities/basic");
```

Comment: Do you mean the API documentation is misleading? I was wondering what they meant. What code should I amend?

Comment: Spot on, it was as above with semi-colon at the end! Add as answer and will confirm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you're referring to is misleading/incorrect. When you talk about `Session` (at least in the .NET world) you talk about the server-side. You're obviously a client of the API, rather than a developer of it, so they asking you to put stuff in the `Session` is incorrect.

You're a client, passing headers in your requests, so it's just:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-version", "2");
```

Side note, you may want to reuse that `HttpClient` instance if you are going to make that call often.
Side note 2: you may want to ask them to fix the docs :)